# How can I add events to a PictureBox dynamically created by clicking button? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I'm creating dynamically a bunch of PictureBoxes by clicking a button in my form, but I'm not clear on how can I add an event to each one. Here's my idea

```
private void insertarBloqueToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pbA = new PictureBox{
        Name = "picturebox" + contB,
        Image = new Bitmap(bloque),
        Size = pbA.Image.Size,
    };
    pbA.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pbA_MouseDown);
    pbA.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(pbA_MouseUp);
    pbA.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pbA_MouseMove);
    pbA.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pbA_Paint);
    pbA.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    listaBloques.Add(pbA);
    panel1.Controls.Add(pbA);
}
```

That's what I got, can you help me with that idea? And How can I can create a single method to move one PictureBox on the list? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is quite good!
But it would be enought to write (but yours works also fine):

```
pbA.Paint += pbA_Paint;// generally: ... += methodName;
```

And you have to create the event itselve. For example:

```
void pbA_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //do some cool stuff!
}
```

If it is painted on **any** of the PictureBoxes then this method will be called. If you want to know which PictureBox has been painted on then simply write:

```
void pbA_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picBox_active = sender as PictureBox;
    //do some cool stuff!
}
```

And for making one single method to move just one PictureBox you could give the desired object as a parameter:

```
void move(PictureBox picBox, int moveX, int moveY)
{
    picBox.Location = new Point(moveX, moveY);
}
```

And you can call this method by:

```
PictureBox picBoxTest = new PictureBox();
move(picBoxTest, 5, 5);
```

And to make it clearer with an example:

```
void pbA_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picBox_active = sender as PictureBox;
    move(picBox_active, 5, 5);
}
```

The PictureBox that has been painted will be moved to the coordinates 5,5.

Comment: That applies to every single method I mentioned into de code? Ahd I forgot to put the "ContB++" line in there.

Comment: Also, I already have the "Drag and drop" Events (I forgot to mention that, it isn't a 'move' method, it's a ´drag and drop' method)

Comment: Yes, you have to do the same procedure for every single event, but not for every single object. Every time you create a new PictureBox with this code you tell your new object to call the method conected to the event. This happens every time. So every object will call the same method. The method itselve ( `pba_Paint()` ) has to be written just once.